# Document document is not defined javascript in Google apps Script

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I can't run my code in the Google Apps Script editor. Clicking **Run** gives the error `document is undefined`.

I am trying to create a function that separates a String into substrings using a separator character and returns those substrings in an array.

```js
function splitSrt(str, delim) {
  var word = "";
  var num = 0;
  str = str + delim;
  var x = str.length;
  var substr_list = [];

  for( var i = 0; i < x; i++){
    if(str[i] != delim)
      word = word + str[i];
      else{
        if(word.length != 0)
          substr_list.push(word);

      word = "";
      }
  }
  return substr_list;
}

var str = "hello my world";
var delim = ' ';
var res = splitSrt(str, delim);
res.forEach(a => {
  document.write( a + "<br>");
});
```

Comment: What is `document.write( a + "<br>");`?

Comment: Google apps script execute server side, e.g. there is no DOM and no document object. What are you trying to do?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ReferenceError: "document" is not defined](/q/13552250/90527)

Answer (score 2):

The code you quote will not work in Apps Script because it is attempting to write to a web page through the [DOM](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Document_Object_Model) method [document.write()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write), which is not available in server-side code such as Node.js or Apps Script.

> The problem is "function that separates a String into substrings using a passable character and returns them in an array"

You probably do not need to write a function for that. Simply use [String.split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split), like this:

```js
function test() {
  const str = "hello my world";
  const delim = ' ';
  const res = str.split(delim);
  res.forEach(word => {
    console.log(word);
  });
}
```

For more complex splitting, use a [regular expression](http://www.regular-expressions.info/quickstart.html) as the separator.

If you really need to create your own string splitter function, start with something like this:

```js
function splitSrt(str, delim) {
  return String(str).split(delim);
}
```